# WcfTestClient method take base class as param

Tags: wcf, wcftestclient

I have the following method signature being exposed via WCF:

```
public void MethodA(RequestBase request)
{

}

public class RequestA : RequestBase
{

}
```

There are some concrete classes derived from the RequestBase Class.  During the service call using WcfTestClient.exe, how do i pass the actual concrete class (RequestA) to the RequestBase in methodA ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [KnownType attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) for your data contracts:

```
[DataContract]
public class RequestBase
{
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(RequestBase))]
public class RequestA : RequestBase
{
}
```

Then you can pass in a `RequestA` object where `RequestBase` is the expected type of the service operation:

```
var requestA = new RequestA();
serviceClient.MethodA(requestA);
```